# django tutorial--returning generic object instead of my text

Tags: python, django, django-models, read-eval-print-loop

Im working through django tutorial right now, and when I go to create a choice for my poll, but I keep on returning the generic choice as opposed to the text I enter.

```
In [19]: q.choice_set.all()
Out[19]: []

In [20]: q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)
Out[20]: <Choice: Choice object>
```

i get 'Choice object' instead of 'Not much'

this is my existing code for mysite.settings path:

`class Question(models.Model):

```
quest_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.quest_text

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

class Choice(models.Model):

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode___(self):
    return self.choice_text`
```

and **now** im getting this:

`In [17]: Question.objects.all()
Out[17]: <repr(<django.db.models.query.QuerySet at 0x10530bbd0>) failed: AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'unicode'>`

Answer (score 3):

The method you are calling is instiating and returning a new `Choice` object, not a new `str` instance. So you see in the REPL exactly what you are supposed to see: `<Choice: Choice object>` is the default representation of a Choice instance.

If you don't like the default representation, implement the `__unicode__` and the `__repr__` methods (or `__str__` for Py3k+):

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    # ... other stuff you already have here ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.unicode()
```

This probably is covered later in the tutorial, so finishing it is a good idea before asking here.

Comment: I have already added the __unicode__ to my models, see below:
`class Choice(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode___(self):
        return self.choice_text`

Comment: please, update the question instead, the comment system does not preserve formatting and it is a must for a language like python.

Comment: Ok, forgot the `__repr__` method.

Answer (score 3):

Since `<Choice: Choice object>` is not a helpful representation of the object, you can add a `__str__()` (or `__unicode__()` for Python 2) method to each of your models.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    #.. Other model stuff you already have 
    def __str__(self):             
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    # ... Other model stuff you already have 
    def __str__(self):              
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: Was running into this issue using __unicode__ with Python 3 and this worked out great. Thanks!